# Unable to fetch Top 100 sku's by sales using SUMX function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to create a new measure to get the Top 100 (N) sku's by sales in Power BI using data models access via the analytic services.

Using the below Query

```
Top_100_sku =
SUMX (
    TOPN (
        100,
        SUMMARIZE ( 
            Sales, 
            'Product Item'[SKU], 
            "Top 100 skus", [Crt Yr Net Sales] 
        ),
        [Crt Yr Net Sales]
    ),
    [Crt Yr Net Sales]
)
```

There is no result for the above.

Expecting to use this measure to get the contribution of Top N to overall sales

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find current year net sales for top 100 SKUs?

Given that you already have a measure of current year net sales, you just want to evaluate this with a proper filter from your set of products/SKUs.

A way to do this is to use the table returned by `TOPN` as a filter, instead of using the resulting table as a basis for iteration.

Try this instead:

```
Top 100 SKU Net Sales = 
VAR _top_products = 
    TOPN ( 
        100 , 
        VALUES ( 'Product Item'[SKU] ),
        [Crt Yr Net Sales],
        DESC 
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Crt Yr Net Sales] , 
        _top_products
    )
```

Note that `TOPN` does not guarantee N values returned, it will yield all tied values at N'th place. For more information, refer to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax